# How to sort persistant data?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am making a application in which I am storing many dates in long in persistant object.

I want to make a list of these long value in asending order, whenever a new value comes, inside the persistence, our list is sorted.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use net.rim.device.api.util.SimpleSortingVector to store your data.

Answer (score 2):

Like oxigen said, use the SimpleSortingVector... which is not simple at first glance!

You have to create a comparator class to pass into the sorting vector.  See example:

```
// Your hashtable with key value pairs
Hashtable data = getMyHashTableWithSomeDataInIt();

// Your sorting vector
SimpleSortingVector sorted = new SimpleSortingVector();

// Iterate through you hashtable and add the keys to the sorting vector
for (Enumeration e = data.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
{
    String key = (String) e.nextElement();
    sorted.addElement(key);
}

// Pass in the comparator and sort the keys
sorted.setSortComparator(new MyComparator());
sorted.reSort();

// Iterate through your sorted vector
for (Enumeration e = sorted.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
{
    String key = (String) e.nextElement();
    Object sortedItem  = (Object) data.get(key);

    // Do whatever you have to with the sortedItem
}

// Sort compartor for sorting strings
class MyComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
        return ((((String) k1).compareTo((String) k2)));
    }
}
```